# What is the reason that a compiler would not treat every variable as a __block variable?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, objective-c-blocks, clang

What are the performance gains of a compiler (specifically compilers that Xcode uses) not treating every variable as a __block variable? I'd imagine there has to be something, I doubt that during the conception of __block variables it was decided that

```
 __block SelfClass * blockSelf = self;
```

is nice and convenient syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The goal of blocks was to make it as automatic and transparent as possible to use blocks with minimal syntax and have them "just work".

Non-__block variables, as the default, are much more in line with the notion of "closures" that blocks represent.  A block snapshots the state of all variables referenced within the block at the moment execution passes over the block declaration.   This encompasses both copying of memory/state and retaining any Objective-C object references captured in the block.

`__block` effectively breaks the encapsulation of state within the block.  Very useful, but requires manual management of object references on the part of the programmer.

I.e. non-__block variables "just work" more often the __block variables and, thus, the default behavior was to gravitate to "just works".

In practice, the cost of capturing the state within a block is typically minimal.   Measurable impact on app performance is typically rare and often indicates an architectural problem of a more profound nature.

---

If by:

```
 __block SelfClass * blockSelf = self;
```

Are you are referring to the cross-product of Blocks and ARC?   Yes, that is a bit unfortunate.  But the compiler is also warning about a very real issue that you need to be aware of.  However, a cleaner workaround would be obviously preferable.

Answer (score 0):

Because `__block` might survive stack destruction. This will only be noticeable with c++ scoped variables:

```
{
    __block shared_ptr<A> ptr = make_shared(new A);
    self.some_block = ^(void){};
} // ptr will not be deleted until the block is destructed
{
   shared_ptr<A> ptr = make_shared(new A);
    self.some_block = ^(void){};
} // ptr will be deleted here
```

It is also noticeable with garbage collection but its much less noticeable and hard to make example of.

Comment: Not quite;  in both cases, the block is a stack scoped block and, thus, will be destructed with the scope.   You have to copy the block to cause it to survive the scope.   As well, this is but one small detail of `__block`;  there war many other driving factors.